# Could not find byebug-3.5.1 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, byebug

I am making a rather simple Rails app with Rails 4.1.6. Initially, I used Ruby version 1.9.3 (which is what I used for another project, and this Ruby version was set as default), but half way through the app I decided to change the Ruby version to the most recent 2.1.3 (`rvm use 2.1.3`). After the change of the Ruby version, I re-bundled.

For debugging purposes, I added pry, because debugger doesn't work with recent versions of Ruby:

Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
end
```

Now every time I try to enter the rails console (`rails c`), I get the following error:

`Could not find byebug-3.5.1 in any of the sources`

Which is strange, because the list of gems printed out in the console after bundling contains the following:

```
Using byebug 3.5.1
<...>
Using pry 0.10.1
Using pry-byebug 2.0.0
Using pry-rails 0.3.2
```

and the command `bundle show byebug`

returns:

`/home/<my home directory>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/byebug-3.5.1`

I tried to `bundle update` and to delete the Gemfile.lock and re-bundle, but the error remains. Could you suggest how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a stroke of luck, I found an answer [here](https://jasonplayne.com/web-dev/rails-generate-could-not-find-in-any-of-the-sources).

Apparently, Rails 4.1 uses something called "springs". I have no idea what they are, but it seems they were interfering with the rails console. After I killed the springs, the console started working.

Looks like black magic. If anyone could explain what these springs are and why they were preventing rails console from starting, I would be much obliged.